# Browser Freezing on function call Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

the function loadPage is causing the browser to freeze on each load.

if i uncomment `$("#responsedcontainer").load("widget.php");`
it doesn't cause the browser to freeze, but if using function loadPage it does. If just using the load feature, none of the other functions run.

I am very limited on my jquery, and trying to learn.  Hope this makes sense.

```
var beforeLoadData = [];

    function loadPage( url ){
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.open("GET", url , false);
        ajax.send(null);
        $("#responsedcontainer").html( ajax.responseText );
    }

    function saveTableData(){
        beforeLoadData = []       
        $("td.changeable").each( function(){
            beforeLoadData.push( { "key": $(this).attr('id'), "value": $(this).text() } );
        }); 
    }

    function getSavedValueFor( key ){
        for( var i in beforeLoadData ){
            if( beforeLoadData[i].key === key )
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    function checkTableData(){
        $("td.changeable").each( function(){
            var thisValue = { "key": $(this).attr('id'), "value": $(this).text() };
            var index = getSavedValueFor( thisValue.key );
            if( index >= 0){
                if( beforeLoadData[index].value > thisValue.value )
                    $( "td#"+thisValue.key ).addClass( 'updated' );
                if( beforeLoadData[index].value < thisValue.value )
                    $( "td#"+thisValue.key ).addClass( 'minus' );  
                } 

        });
    }

    function removeUpdatedClass( ){
        setTimeout( function(){
            $('td.updated').removeClass('updated');
            $('td.minus').removeClass('minus');
        },4000);
    }


    $(function(){
        saveTableData();
        //$("#responsedcontainer").load("widget.php");
        loadPage( "widget.php" );
        checkTableData();
        removeUpdatedClass();
        var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
            saveTableData();
            //$("#responsedcontainer").load("widget.php?randval="+ Math.random());
            loadPage("widget.php?randval="+ Math.random());
            checkTableData();
            removeUpdatedClass();
        }, 5000);
    });
```

Comment: jQuery has a built in `$.ajax()` function why are you creating an XMLHttpRequest object? It might be the cause of freezing because older browsers don't support that object, an `ActiveXObject` is used and I think there's another as well

Answer (score 3):

The line `ajax.open("GET", url , false);` should be `ajax.open("GET", url , true);`.

The third parameter (boolean) is whether the request should be async, which would be a non-DOM-blocking call for the data.

Comment: If i change to true, the page doesn't load at all

Comment: That's because you're using AJAX, so the script isn't executing in order; you don't have a callback attached to your AJAX request for the response to call into. I'd recommend just using jQuery's built-in AJAX methods which will handle this for you.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, i tried this code:

`function loadPage( url ){
        $.ajax({
    url: url,
    cache: false
  }).done(function( html ) {
    $("#responsedcontainer").html(html);
  });
        
    }`

It works, but then the functions don't call.  Sorry, i do not know jquery well.